# show hidden element with css

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="mobile">Some mobile content</div>
```

This content is hidden by default (core.css):

```
.mobile{display: none;}
```

Now, I want to show this div, when browser resolution is lower than 1024px and it doesn't work:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .mobile{display: block;}
}
```

How can I show this div? Opposite way works fine - showing and then hiding when resolution changes.

Comment: You could throw a `!important` in there, but I don't know if that is the best solution.

Comment: is the @media part above or below the plain part? And is there a <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> tag in your head?

Comment: Also: You could try to add some specificity points by adding "body" in front of the .@media class. @media (max-width: 1024px) {body .mobile{display: block;} }

Comment: @thatidiotguy - give me the right solution: .mobile{display: block !important;}. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Johan: I have this meta tag in <head>.

Comment: @repincln Please don't go for the !important fix. Use CSS specificity like Karl-André Gagnon suggests.

Comment: @Johan: I use Karl Andre Gagnos sugestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you use the same selector, it will always use the last called selector.

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9KtHg/

It is working perfectly since the media query is called last (so it override the CSS when the condition are met).

But here : http://jsfiddle.net/9KtHg/1/

It is not working since the `display:none` is last and will override the other CSS.

To avoid that, you need to use greater specificity selector in the media query like :

```
div.mobile <-the tag name containing class='mobile'
[.][#][tag]parent .mobile <- use the parent in the selector
.mobile{display:block!important}<- using important is a bad pratice, avoid it.
```

You could also include the `core.css` before your CSS files containing your mediaqueries.

In conclusion, welcome to the fabulous world of CSS override!

By the way, CSS mean "*cascading style sheets*". As it said in its name, it work as a cascade where the last declared CSS will be used!

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation. This also works and now I figure out the problem.